# Delete a data stored as a list within another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

The case is as follows: I have created a code that, based on some criteria, gives me a printed list per screen.

```
data = [[ 17,     0,     0,      0,    2.5,   'A+',    450],
        [ 18,     5,     0,      5,    2.5,   'A+',    450],
        [ 19,     9,     0,      9,    2.5,   'A+',    450],
        [ 20,     0,   2.5,      0,      5,   'A+',    450],
        [ 21,     5,   2.5,      5,      5,   'A+',    450],
        [ 22,     0,   2.5,      5,    2.5,   'B-',    400],
        [ 23,     5,   2.5,      9,    2.5,   'B-',    400],
        [ 24,     0,     5,      5,      5,   'B-',    400]] 

pairs =  []

for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data)):
        if data[i][3] == data[j][1] and data[i][4] == data[j][2]:
            pairs.append([data[i][0], data[j][0]])
#        if data[i][5] == 'B-' and data[i][5] == data[i+1][5]:
#            pairs.append([data[i][0], data[j][0]])            
print(pairs)
```

But now I want to delete - in this case - the list that contains the pair [22, 23], since it meets 2 conditions:

- The first is that it is 2 consecutive numbers.
- The second is that both are of type 'B-' **(data [i] [5] = 'B-')**

I only want to eliminate those that meet those two conditions, the list would be like this (For illustrative purposes):

```
[[17, 20], [17, 22], [18, 21], [18, 23], [20, 24], [22, 21]]
```

I have tried creating with another conditional where I include the mentioned points but I have indexing errors, I think there is some way to correct that, I would really appreciate your help. Regards.

Comment: you have to give more details about your conditions. What do you mean by two consecutive numbers? And are you looking for only B- or you want everything checked?

Comment: Is your first column always increasing?

Comment: Yes, @iamvegan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you alter your commented-out code a little you should get what you're requesting:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data)):
        if data[i][3] == data[j][1] and data[i][4] == data[j][2]:
            if (not (data[i][5] == data[j][5] == 'B-')) and data[i][0]+1 != data[j][0]:
                 pairs.append([data[i][0], data[j][0]])     

print(pairs)
```

Comment: For some reason I feel `not (data[i][5] == data[i+1][5] == 'B-')` would read better.